# Optimized algorithm for line-sphere intersection in GLSL

Tags: opengl, mathematics, performance, raycasting

Well, hello then!

I need to find intersection between line and sphere in GLSL. Right now my solution is based on [Paul Bourke's page](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) and was ported to GLSL this way:

```
// The line passes through p1 and p2:
vec3 p1 = (...);
vec3 p2 = (...);

// Sphere center is p3, radius is r:
vec3 p3 = (...);
float r = ...;

float x1 = p1.x; float y1 = p1.y; float z1 = p1.z;
float x2 = p2.x; float y2 = p2.y; float z2 = p2.z;
float x3 = p3.x; float y3 = p3.y; float z3 = p3.z;

float dx = x2 - x1;
float dy = y2 - y1;
float dz = z2 - z1;

float a = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;
float b = 2.0 * (dx * (x1 - x3) + dy * (y1 - y3) + dz * (z1 - z3));
float c = x3*x3 + y3*y3 + z3*z3 + x1*x1 + y1*y1 + z1*z1 - 2.0 * (x3*x1 + y3*y1 + z3*z1) - r*r;

float test = b*b - 4.0*a*c;

if (test >= 0.0) {
  // Hit (according to Treebeard, "a fine hit").
  float u = (-b - sqrt(test)) / (2.0 * a);
  vec3 hitp = p1 + u * (p2 - p1);
  // Now use hitp.
}
```

It works perfectly! But it seems slow... I'm new at GLSL. You can answer this questions in two ways:

1. Tell me there is no solution, showing some proof or strong evidence.
2. Tell me about GLSL features (vector APIs, primitive operations) that makes the above algorithm faster, showing some example.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems slow? Have you tested this? How slow is it? Is it causing performance issues with your game? Remember what Knuth said: **"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"**

Comment: Yes, my framerate is less than 20fps on a good machine. I removed most of other code, so I guess the problem is there. The above code runs on a fragment shader (pixel shader).

Comment: How often are you calling this code? Is your framerate still low with *this* code removed?

Comment: Just as a very obvious observation: running it in the fragment shader is usually a bad idea for large objects.. you get sensibly more pixels than vertices in the processing pipeline.. so that's one potential performance sucker. Otherwise, it seems fairly simple as not to overburden the gpu.

Comment: I know, teodron. But I need to draw perfect spheres at arbitrary resolutions. I've tried to build spheres out of triangles and enable anti-aliasing for them to be perfect, but it became much slower (and more complicated) than building it on the fragment shader.

Comment: Then, may I ask why you need to perform such a test in the pixel shader? I don't get the general idea, you can render the sphere with nice results in the PS, but why do you need to perform collision/hit detection in the PS as well?

Comment: I'm trying to build a photo-realistic ray-traced animation. There will be mirroring, smoke and shadows cast by scene objects.

Comment: Photo-realistic ray-traced animation with mirrors, smoke and shadows, and you want *better* than 20fps?

Comment: Actually, I only want to make that algorithm faster. That's a very simple question. I don't understand why people can't be more direct and objective in these forums. I don't want to tell my entire doomed history. I don't want to replace my work with 3rd party. I just want to know if that algorithm can be faster using some sort of GLSL primitives, like vector APIs! Tell me, GLSL experts, is that so hard to answer?

Comment: I'm no GLSL expert, but what strikes me about the code is that it does not use any vector functions. Not only would appropriate use of vector functions make the source code a lot smaller and more readable, with the right compiler it's also potentially a lot faster.

Comment: I really don't think this code is your problem.  It's doing a number of operations on par with a single 4x4 matrix multiplication, which will be stupidly fast in hardware.  The only slow call you have is the sqrt function.  Try removing this code and see what framerate you get.

Comment: @fernacolo: "I don't understand why people can't be more direct and objective in these forums." Because most of the time, when people ask 'make my code faster,' they're doing it out of a misplaced sense belief that taking the time to do so is actually worthwhile for their application. Plus, there's the simple fact that GLSL doesn't define *performance*. Various things *might* increase performance, but there's no guarantee of it for any particular compiler. So your question is basically unanswerable in the general case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for these separate `x1`, `x2` etc. variables. You can compute `a`, `b` and `c` in fewer instructions using vector operations:

```
vec3 d = p2 - p1;

float a = dot(d, d);
float b = 2.0 * dot(d, p1 - p3);
float c = dot(p3, p3) + dot(p1, p1) - 2.0 * dot(p3, p1) - r*r;
```

It is possible the compiler will notice this, but there is no reason to make it harder than it already is to optimise GLSL compilation.

Comment: Very good! From 16fps, I got 19fps! Thanks a lot!